# Module name "mysql" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, cordova, module

I am using Apache cordova tools in visual studio community. I am writing a hybrid app in Javascript. I encountered this error while setting connection to MySQL database:
Module name "mysql" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

My code is

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

            var connection =  mysql.createConnection({
                host : "localhost",
                user : "root",
                password: "root"
            });

                connection.connect();

                connection.query("use verify");
                var strQuery = "select * from table1";  

                connection.query( strQuery, function(err, rows){
                    if(err) {
                        throw err;
                    }else{
                        console.log( rows );
                    }
                });
```

Error pops up on the first line.
I installed mysql using both

```
npm install mysql
```

and

```
npm install -g mysql
```

with usual command prompt and the one with node.js but the problem persists.
I also copied mysql folder from nodejs to root folder of application but still problem persists.

Comment: The error comes from require.js, which uses a slightly different sematic for `require()` than node.

Comment: I have included require.js in my application folder, so what is it that I am lacking?

Comment: the "standard" requirejs syntax is `require( ['module'], function( module ) { /* your code */ });` So the callback is triggered, when the module is loaded, but the loading is not blocking. But I never used it together with Cordova.

Comment: I am much of a newbie to js, can you write the code above in your format?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have never worked with Cordova and hence have no clue, whether this will work:

The semantic of `require()` in RequireJS is slightly different from the one in NodeJS: NodeJS loads the module synchronously. Hence your code can be processed immediately after. In RequireJS, however, the code is loaded asynchronously. So we have to specify a callback, what to do, when the module has been loaded. So in case that is the root of the problem, your code should look something like this:

```
require( ['mysql'], function( mysql ) {
  var connection =  mysql.createConnection({
                      host : "localhost",
                      user : "root",
                      password: "root"
                    });

  connection.connect();

  connection.query("use verify");
  var strQuery = "select * from table1";  

  connection.query( strQuery, function(err, rows){
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }else{
      console.log( rows );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unhandled exception at line 23, column 21 in ms-appx://io.cordova.blankcordovaapp2/www/index.html
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'createConnection' of undefined or null reference
File: index.html, Line: 23, Column: 21
This error popped up

Comment: Are you sure anyway`s, that you have access to a MySQL database in the target environment? Never heard of a MySQL server running on a mobile phone.

Comment: Its not running on mobile currently. I am testing the code on win 8.1 first.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on accessing MySQL directly from Cordova. All results use MySQL on a server and Cordova accesses that server. If they want to store data within the application (without a server), they use `localStorage`. See [Storage@Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)

Comment: But how to connect the server if the mysql module isn't getting loaded?

Comment: You set up a server backend with some language like PHP, e.g., and connect to that interface with AJAX.

Comment: Is that the only option??

Comment: The other option is the aforementioned  `localStorage`.

Comment: But other users can't access local storage

Comment: If you want to connect multiple users, you need a server anyways and it is _not_ recommended to let your users connect directly to the database without any input sanitizing.